# Fire Native Keyboard Events on Web Elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, dom-events

I am working on an onscreen keyboard and would like to fire `Keypress`, `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` on HTML input elements. Since I am only sending the current keypresses I do not have to deal with caret position, whether to delete or append or any other complex logic. Just as I am simulating the actual keypresses.

Basically I want to change the value of a input box by sending keyboard events only. I do not want Jquery on this.

PS: I am using react on the DOM. If I can send the events to the React and if it is picking it up, that is good enough too.

Comment: the keyPress you can do with creating events. the whole thing together i'm not sure about.

Comment: tried with createEvents and dispatching. It works for click events but not for keyboard events. I tried with the sequence as well. Still no luck :(

Comment: To be able to send direct keyboard input such as keys like "QWERTY" is a major security issue and is not allowed, cross browser, via JS alone. There are ways around, most browser based and require a user download, but you can't `sendkeys` in JS.

Comment: also, personal opinion, i wouldn't use react to save mine or my family's life ...

Comment: @SpYk3HH thanks for the reply.  The app im using the onscreen keyboard for is a react app. so if I can tap into that listener, that is good enough too. Something like calling their event handler on the dom component with the event data i want.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure I follow you. You can capture keycodes and get the letter with stuff like `charAt`, but if you're trying to simulate pressing a key, you can't. You can simulate an action related, but you cannot simulate the actual event of pressing the key and sending a character to the screen. in other languages that's called "sendkeys", most often. but it doesn't exist in js due to security issues, and therefor won't exist in react, since react is nothing more than a lib of js. react is just an alternate to angular or jquery, but it's nothing more special than that.